# Is there a JPA provider which stores in XML format and not for a RDBMS?

Tags: java, xml, jpa

DataNucleues for example does it but I don't like the preprocessing (their JPA implementation is based on JDO). Are there other alternatives? The format of the XML-file doesn't really matter.

We use JPA already and store to a RDBMS. I don't need new design approach but just if there is such a solution to persist in XML. My question is not "Is it a good idea to persist with JPA to XML?"

Comment: Why do you care if it stores the data in an XML or an RDBMS?  If you're using JPA, you're going to be using the same API either way.  And how does a datastore create indexes on an XML file?

Comment: Index is just for performance and not necessary. It should work like HSQLDB that can use an SQL-dump, but the rest is in memory.

Comment: I have deleted my post, because it will add no value. Anyway why do you do not use anything that is designed for act with XML instead of JPA?

Comment: The JPA implementation of DataNucleus is not based on JDO. We simply make use of the JDO **bytecode enhancement contract**. Other JPA providers use bytecode enhancement, such as OpenJPA. Guess what is the origin of the bytecode enhancement contract used by OpenJPA? Yes, JDO also. DataNucleus v3.0 does not have any JPA layer on top of JDO.

Answer (score 2):

EclipseLink includes both JPA and JAXB support to allow both database and XML mapping.  You can use JAXB to serialize an object model to a file or stream.  EclipseLink also has EIS support for non-relational databases including XML data sources (an XML file adapter is included).

In general if you are just looking for a light weight database, I would recommend an embedded Java database such as Derby or HSQL.